# Jersey Netbeans Date format

Tags: java, date-format, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey2 rest server that's transmitting `java.util.Date` in the following format

```
Receiving from Jersey2 REST Server
2017-01-11T00:00:00Z

Android Retrofit Client receives/sends as
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" )
2017-01-11T00:00:00+0000
```

For some reasons when I send the date back to the server, the birthday is not mapped and showing as null. Is there a way to troubleshoot this? I'm sure the field name is valid and possibly the date format too..:/ Is there something that I missed? I want to standardize the date format in jersey but Im not sure how.

```
public class Account..{
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date birthday;

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

}

public class AccountFacadeREST ...{
    @POST
    @Path("create")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response createPassbyProfile(Account entity, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        try {
           super.create(entity);
        }
    }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Wouldn’t `TemporalType.DATE` be more appropriate?

Comment: Also can you use the modern `LocalDate` instead of the outdated `Date`? Asking with no experience whatsoever with any newer JPA version, but reading that it should contain support for Java 8 date and time API.

Comment: the code does not compile. createPassByProfile is wrong [MCVE] is needed

Comment: I have figured out the problem. It worked after I removed the Z on setdateformat. Now that one thing is solved I can change it to TemporalType.Date.

Comment: @OleV.V.  This is my first time writing REST and in Java because I wrote in C# light years ago. I couldn't find the option to set Java8 for my project so end up using 7.